# php round int to 3 digits

Tags: php, formatting, numbers, rounding

The raw

```
var_dump float(0.00236669101534).
```

My calculation will always be between `0.0010 / 0.0060`.

I want to show the user:
`float(23,7)` rounding upwards.

I'm currently doing the following:

```
$var = round(intval(substr($var, 4)), -9); // float(237000000000)
```

I've tried exploding it and concatenating it but I want my var to be a float/int for validation purposes.

Any help is appriciated!

Rob

Comment: Why not to multiply with 1000 first and then apply round with presicision = 2 or 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

To show the user 23.7 you can use following

```
floatval(round($var * 10000, 1));
```

Although internally precision can be lost when multiplying float by 10000.

I don't know what you mean by validation purposes, but PHP does conversion between types under the hood, so results given by floatval() may be overriden by some actions.

Actually floatval is not needed since round returns float, so this can be simply

```
round($var * 10000, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. The precision may be off by .3 so this isn't a big deal!